# WordPress : is_page_template not working when called from wp_enqueue_scripts action

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to enqueue different css files depending on the page template I use.

The function is_page_template("index.php") called from wp_enqueue_scripts action function (where all styles and scripts are called) always returns false. I am certain that I use index.php template - it is also reported by "What the file" plugin as the working template.

What is the way to get the page template with respect of adding scripts to the html header?

```
function the_scripts() {

    if( is_page_template('index.php') ) {
        print "this is index.php";
    } else {
        print "failed";
    }
}

    wp_enqueue_style( [style_1], [path_1] );
    ...
    wp_enqueue_style( [style_n], [path_n] );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'the_scripts' );
```

Comment: It should be `is_home()`. `index.php` is not a page template, so `is_page_template()` will always return false

Comment: Pieter is right, however there's still an issue of `is_page_template()` not working until the template has been loaded. So if you want to check a page other than index, you should use `is_page()`. But if you really want to use `is_page_template()` instead, this might be relevant to you: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/is_page_template-in-functionsphp-not-working

Comment: suggested by this resource putting this in functions.php:
    $template_name = get_post_meta( $wp_query->post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true )

does not get the template name so it does not then run the remaining functions properly without properly populating this variable. still stuck.

Comment: Pieter was right: index.php is not a page template. is_page_template( "page_name" ) works very fine in the_scripts() as long as long as is_page_template() returns true which is when the page is template based. but here is the trick: even if it is based the a template it will return false if it is assigned to be the main blog in Personalization!

Answer (score 0):

I think ( is_page() && !is_page_template() ) will work in the wp_enqueue_scripts hook to check if the Default Page Template is in use.